# Create a Chart for Membership Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Was wondering how to best set up data to create charts for memberships.

I want to create a chart that compares # of New Members vs. # of Cancelled members. In the data, I have one columns that contains their start date (for subscribing) and one column that contains their cancellation date.

I'm not sure how to best set this up so that I can create a line or bar chart.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170131/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in columns `A1:C` and looks like this:

| Name | Started | Cancelled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jayne | 4/10/2023 | 7/21/2023 |
| Melanie | 4/10/2023 | 4/27/2023 |
| Victoria | 4/11/2023 |  |
| Geri | 4/12/2023 |  |
| Emma | 4/29/2023 |  |
| John | 5/16/2023 |  |
| Paul | 4/10/2023 |  |
| George | 4/27/2023 | 7/21/2023 |
| Ringo | 4/29/2023 |  |

...you can unpivot the data so it looks like this:

| Name | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jayne | Started | 4/10/2023 |
| Jayne | Cancelled | 7/21/2023 |
| Melanie | Started | 4/10/2023 |
| Melanie | Cancelled | 4/27/2023 |
| Victoria | Started | 4/11/2023 |
| Geri | Started | 4/12/2023 |
| Emma | Started | 4/29/2023 |
| John | Started | 5/16/2023 |
| Paul | Started | 4/10/2023 |
| George | Started | 4/27/2023 |
| George | Cancelled | 7/21/2023 |
| Ringo | Started | 4/29/2023 |

...and then aggregate and re-pivot the data so it looks like this:

**By date:**

| Date | Cancelled | Started |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/10/2023 |  | 3 |
| 4/11/2023 |  | 1 |
| 4/12/2023 |  | 1 |
| 4/27/2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 4/29/2023 |  | 2 |
| 5/16/2023 |  | 1 |
| 7/21/2023 | 2 |  |

**By week:**

| Date | Cancelled | Started |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-w15 |  | 5 |
| 2023-w17 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-w20 |  | 1 |
| 2023-w29 | 2 |  |

**By month:**

| Date | Cancelled | Started |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04 | 1 | 8 |
| 2023-05 |  | 1 |
| 2023-07 | 2 |  |

**By year:**

| Date | Cancelled | Started |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 3 | 9 |

Here's one way to unpivot the data:

```
=let( 

  table, A1:C, 
  numColsToRepeat, 1, 

  numColsToSqueeze, columns(table) - numColsToRepeat, 
  headers, { offset(table, 0, 0, 1, numColsToRepeat), "Status", "Date" }, 
  categories, offset(table, 0, 0, 1), 
  colsToRepeat, offset(table, 1, 0, rows(table) - 1, numColsToRepeat), 
  colsToSqueeze, offset(table, 1, numColsToRepeat, rows(table) - 1, numColsToSqueeze), 
  reduce( 
    headers, colsToSqueeze, 
    lambda( 
      result, cell, 
      if( 
        cell = "", 
        result, 
        { 
          result; 
          { 
            index(colsToRepeat, row(cell) - row(colsToSqueeze) + 1), 
            index(categories, 1, column(cell) - column(table) + 1), 
            cell 
          } 
        } 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula assumes that the data is in columns `A1:C`.

Here's one example of how to aggregate and re-pivot the unpivoted data:

```
=let( 
  data, filter(E1:G, len(E1:E)), 
  aggregation, 
    "select Col3, count(Col1) 
     where Col3 is not null 
     group by Col3 
     pivot Col2", 
  names, choosecols(data, 1), 
  statuses, choosecols(data, 2), 
  dates, choosecols(data, 3), 
  twoDigit_, lambda(n, text(n, "00")), 
  day_, lambda(d, to_date(d)), 
  week_, lambda(d, iferror(year(d) & "-w" & twoDigit_(weeknum(d)), d)), 
  month_, lambda(d, text(d, "yyyy-MM")), 
  year_, lambda(d, iferror(year(d), d)), 
  getData_, lambda(period_, { names, statuses, map(dates, period_) } ), 
  report, query(getData_(month_), aggregation, 1 ), 
  report 
)
```

The formula assumes that the unpivoted data is in columns `E1:G`.

To change between daily, weekly, monthly and yearly reporting, replace the `month_` in `getData_(month_)` with `day_`, `week_`, `month_` or `year_`.

To create a chart, select the resulting table and choose **Insert > Chart**.